# I keep getting a "ReferenceError: transfer is not defined" error in my terminal after using truffle, ill write the code for the deployment below

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

```
const Tether = artifacts.require('Tether')
const Reward = artifacts.require('Reward')
const DBank = artifacts.require('DBank')

module.exports = async function (deployer, network, accounts) {
await deployer.deploy(Tether)
const tether = await Tether.deployed()

await deployer.deploy(Reward) 
const reward = await Reward.deployed()

await deployer.deploy(DBank, reward.address, tether.address)
const dbank = await DBank.deployed()

//Transfer all reward tokens to the bank
await transfer(dbank.address, '1000000000000000000000000')

//Distribute 100 tokens to the Investor automatically
await tether.transfer(accounts[1], '100000000000000000')
```

};

The file is a deployment script to deploy smart contracts.
I keep getting a "ReferenceError: transfer is not defined" error in my terminal after using truffle migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to transfer from the `Rewards` contract?

```
//Transfer all reward tokens to the bank
await reward.transfer(dbank.address, '1000000000000000000000000')
```